# Database connection in Slim Framework not working on Ubuntu server but working on windows localhost

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I installed **illuminate/database**
Then entered db credentials in settings.php like

```
'db' => [
            // Eloquent configuration
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
            'username'  => getenv('DB_USER'),
            'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
        ],
```

Then in index.php I put following line before $app->run()

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$capsule = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container->get('settings')['db']);
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
```

Everything works fine at my windows localhost but not works wen I uploaded at ubuntu server.
When I comment the following line **$capsule->bootEloquent();** on the server. I could see slim home page otherwise I gets 500 HTTP error, This page isn’t working. Don't know why this is happening please help.

Comment: What is the error message? You should be able to retrieve it from the server logs

Comment: Is MySQL installed on the Ubuntu server? If so, is your `DB_HOST` set correctly? And does your `DB_USER` exist and have the appropriate rights?

Comment: I'm using remote database which is on another machine. Both my local and server are using same db and db credentials.

Comment: I also checked app.log file there is no log but on home page I'm getting following error : This page isn’t working... HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: I think this php version issue.. let me update the latest php version on my server.. I'll update you soon.